# AVPlayer DecoderNotFound (-11833). Supported codecs for iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I'm barely new to iOS and I'm testing on the simulator.

I'm trying to reproduce a stream via AVPlayer and I'm getting an [AVError DecoderNotFound(-11833)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/averror/averrordecodernotfound?language=objc) in ios simulator.

My guess is that simulator does not support the media type of the stream, anyone could confirm my guess?

In such a case, is there any list of supported codecs for iOS simulator? Shall it be the same as on device?

Comment: should work fine in simulator

Comment: @ReinierMelian I would expect some more technical info.